# custom validation in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm unable to find perfect solution for custom validation for angular application.

We have an input field which is attached to array(list has 2500+ options) now we want to validate for the value user typed against the array which we are unable to do, here is our simple code

```
    var value_array = ["a",c","c"];
    app.directive('validValue', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^form',
            link: function(scope,elem,attr,formController) {
                elem.bind('blur', function() {
                 // no idea what to do from here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `datalist` element to validate against, or use `setCustomValidity` to invalidate the element.

### Using datalist in template(may not require a directive):

```
<input ng-model="model" list="validOptions">
<datalist id="validOptions">
  <option value="red" />
  <option value="green" />
  <option value="blue" />
</datalist>
```

### Using `setCustomValidity`:

to mark the element as valid, pass an empty string `''` to the function, otherwise pass the error message.

```
elem.bind('blur', function() {
  for(let validOption of options) {
    if(validOption === value) {
      return elem[0].setCustomValidity('');
    }
  }
  elem[0].setCustomValidity('Invalid value, try again');
});
```